# Group and subgroup generated by element in G and application of Lagrange' s theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

It might be a stupid question.

Let G be a group and H be a subgroup

If there is "a" in H, then subgroup generated by a is a subgroup of H

Then, order of subgroup generated by a must divide the order of H

Since H is a subgroup, "a" is in G if "a" is in H.

So, subgroup generated by "a" is indeed a subgroup of G.

Then order of subgroup generated by a must divide the order of G

But, it seems to me that order of "a" must be common divisor of order of G and order of H.

Is it right? I am so confused!

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Yes, that's true, although it's even more basic than that: since the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$, a common divisor of the two is nothing more or less than a divisor of the order of $H$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. You have drawn the right conclusion. What is so confusing about it ?

Comment: If the order of G and the order of H are relatively prime and if "a" is in H, subgroup generated by "a" is trivial?

Comment: Yes, because $H$ can only be the trivial group with only the neutral element in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers $k, l$ and $m$ it holds that if $k \mid l$ and $l \mid m$, then $k \mid m$ (divisibility is *transitive*). Now put $k=|\langle a \rangle|$, $l=|H|$ and $m=|G|$, then by Lagrange's Theorem (applied twice!) and the previous remark, $k \mid m$.